# Extract the initial content of an html element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, webbrowser-control

After the page loads, jquery makes a series of modifications. creates child elements, modifies them ... but I need the initial state of the element.

Jquery has the .html () method, but I can not use jquery!

I use webbrowser activex control

Comment: You can get the same functionality of .html() with .innerHTML

Comment: Unless you have somehow already stored the initial html somewhere you can't get it after it has been modified. There is no HTML history record

Comment: the tricky part is to be sure that your code will run before jQuery, which is easier to do with jQuery actually (with holdReady function for example). Can you be more precise on where the html come from? for example if it's loaded via Ajax, it will be a much different case than html from the initial page..

Comment: When you create a child element, innerhtml does not return the initial content without this new element.

Comment: Kadath, I need to know if there is a method that extracts the initial content, since I do not have the option to run the code before jquery!

Comment: you still have the option to request again the page content with Ajax to have the initial content, a bit of overkill maybe, but well. There are methods to get it as DOM elements without executing the JS that transforms it, if i remember well